# I would like to style JS file in react using CSS styling but I'm getting an error

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import './myStyle.css'
function Stylesheet(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Stylesheet</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Stylesheet
```

This I'm getting an error

> ./src/Components/stylesheet.js Module not found: Can't resolve './myStyle.css' in 'D:\Documents\WebProject\React\hello-world\src\Components'

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? And does the file "myStyle.css" exist?

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to create a component for styling a component. Just write your css style and import it like `import './myStyle.css'`

Answer (score -1):

There are different options to style React components.I will explain few options here.

**CSS Stylesheet:**

Add a `Stylesheet.css` file as below.

```
.boxColor {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Add a component `Stylesheet.js`. Simply import css file `import './Stylesheet.css'`

```
import React from 'react';
import './Stylesheet.css';

const Stylesheet = () => (
  <div className="boxColor">
    <p>Get started with CSS styling</p>
  </div>
);

export default Stylesheet;
```

**Inline styling**: In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they are specified with an object.

Add `Stylesheet.js` file.

```
import React from 'react';

const boxColor = {
  background-color: red;
};
    
const Stylesheet = () => (
 <div style={boxColor}>
   <p>Get started with CSS styling</p>
 </div>
);
    
export default Stylesheet;
```

- We can create a variable that stores style properties and then pass
  it to the element like `style={boxColor}`
- We can also pass the styling directly `style={{background-color: 'red'}}`

There few more ways like **Styled-component** and **CSS Modules** to style react component.

Answer (score -1):

for example ,you have two files , first is **practice.js** and second is **style.css** then import your **style.css** in **practice.js** as following.

practice.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css'; //importing style sheet

export default function practice() {
     return (
          <div>
               <h1 className="heading">Hellooooooo</h1>    
          </div>
     )
}
```

and your style.css file is

```
.heading{
     color: white;
     background-color:  black;
}
```